# How to show pdf in modal Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf.js

In my rails application I want users to be able to show pdf in modal so for this I use Iframe with something like this

```
<iframe src="<%= @application.resume.url %>" frameborder="0" style = "height:100%; width:100%;"></iframe>
```

and this is working great but I want that the file to be open with the mozilla pdf reader even if the user use others web browser, So I'm wondering if there is a gem for this?

Comment: what if he doesn't have it?

Comment: @Mhmd I don'tn understand you

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, There is gem called `prawn` which is used to generate pdf files.
But, you want to open iframe in mozilla web pdf reader. So, please use pdf.js for that -

```
<iframe src="http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf" width="500px" height="400px" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work it give this error 
Missing PDF file

Comment: @rocki.......if this is not worked for you. Please try feature with Google Docs. You can embed your pdf with google docs viewer.

Like:

        <a href="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=   {YOUR_PDF_URL}&embedded=true">Your Pdf Viewer</a>

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers should be able to display the .pdf if you use [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file).